# How can I change column type `<dttm>` to `<date>` with `col_types` using `read_xlsx` or `read_excel` in r?

Tags: r

Using R version 3.6.1 on Windows 10. I am trying to change the first column type from `<dttm>` to `<date>` using `read_xlsx` or `read_excel`.

Here is a link to a demo data set https://www.dropbox.com/s/ts1utkyib6hw226/demo.xlsx?dl=0 (dropbox was having some issues, so I hope that works).

Here are some things I've tried and the respective error messages.

```
read_xlsx("demo/demo.xlsx", col_types = list(Date = col_date(format = "%Y-%m-%d")))

## Error in check_col_types(col_types) : is.character(col_types) is not TRUE
```

```
read_xlsx("demo/demo.xlsx", col_types = list(Date = "date"))

## Error in check_col_types(col_types) : is.character(col_types) is not TRUE
```

Or if I make a list of 26 column types, the column type output is still `<dttm>`.

```
read_xlsx("demo/demo.xlsx", col_types = c("date", "guess", "guess", "guess", "guess", "guess", ...)
```

Another try was the `as.Date()` function but returns the following error.

```
read_xlsx("demo/demo.xlsx", col_types = list(Date = as.Date()))

## Error in inherits(x, "Date") : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to change the column types while reading the data ? It would be easy to change data in the format you want after you read it. For example, try

```
transform(readxl::read_xlsx("demo/demo.xlsx"), Date = as.Date(Date))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This worked great. I just needed to keep it as a tibble so I used `%>% as_tibble()` at the end!